# Rails assets pipelines + git submodules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I am trying to use [Skeleton](http://www.getskeleton.com/) with Ruby on Rails. What I want to do is to put the Skeleton directory in the vendor directory as a git submodule in order to have something similar to this:

```
...
vendor/
    ...
    Skeleton/
        ...
        stylesheets/
        robots.txt
```

I tried to add the following line to `config/application.rb`:

```
    config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("vendor", "assets", "Skeleton", "stylesheets")
```

It added the stylesheet folder to the assets pipeline's paths but the files in the stylesheet directory still give a routing error...

How can I make this work please?

PS: I want to have Skeleton as a `git submodule` in `vendor/assets` so separating the files is not an option.

Answer (score 2):

It's depends how you try to use this files. I have made a simple test app with Skeleton as submodule and it works. You can see it [here](https://github.com/korin/Skeleton_test).

If don't want to require skeleton css in application.css and use it as separated precompiled file you neeed tell rails to precompile that file. In your application.rb:

```
config.assets.precompile << 'skeleton.css'
```